# Network printer shows as ready but won't print

Tags: networking, printing, printer

everyone!

I had set up a printer (HP 4500) as a network printer. It is connected via USB to the router (Asus RT-N16). It seems like the router's EZ sharing doesn't work with the HP. So, per Asus's instructions, I set up a TCP/IP connection using LPR protocol with the queue name "LPRServer". On my computer (Win10) it didn't work at first. Though after unplugging the power of the printer and rebooting my computer, it started to work fine. Everyone else's computers (all Win7) worked the first time. It has worked for 2-3 days.

This morning, people were still able to print (and I, myself, printed some things last night). Now, none of us are able to print, even though the printer shows up as ready on everyone's computers. The router shows the printer as "enabled". When we try to print, the printer's status window on our desktops says "printing" for several seconds until it says that there was an error.

I've looked for an answer. Some problems looked similar and were solved by unchecking the SNMP setting, though mine was already unchecked. I've also tried switching to RAW. Also no go.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the actual error to get?  Have you tried power cycling the printer (unplug/replug) again?

Comment: It simply says "Error - Printing". When troubleshooting, it says "An unexpected error has occurred. The troubleshooting wizard can't continue."  More details in the troubleshooting gives error 0x803C010B. I have tried power cycling the printer and rebooting the computers, and this also hasn't worked. When trying to print, the printer's status says "Printing" for several seconds until it changes to "Error - Printing".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the printer has just started working again, and I haven't done anything to it since last night. Someone else turned off the power strip, which is powering both the printer and the router. I turned it back on, and the printing works now. I never thought to restart the router. Perhaps that did it.